# Malformed attribute selector Cheerio

Tags: node.js, request, cheerio

I'm Requesting to a website and getting the html successfully and loading it with cheerio.

The problem is that its erroring

```
const res = await axios.get(download_url);
const $ = cheerio.load(res.data);
let result = $('div[class=w-full mt-6 sm:mt-8 lg:mt-0 lg:w-1/3]').html()
```

So what I think is causing the error is the spaces but what would I have to replace them with?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would either quote the value:

```
div[class="w-full mt-6 sm:mt-8 lg:mt-0 lg:w-1/3"]
```

or use . style:

```
div.w-full.mt-6.sm:mt-8.lg:mt-0.lg:w-1/3
```

Also chances are you don't need to full class:

```
div.w-full.mt-6.sm:mt
```